# Remove block in xml without commenting

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-1, xml

What is a best practice to remove some block without commenting

```
<my_layout_handle>
       <reference name="content">
                <block type="core/template" name="name.button" template="custom/new-button.phtml" /> //remove this block
       </reference>
</my_layout_handle>
```

**EDIT:**

This is what I was looking for:

```
<my_layout_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="unsetChild">
           <block type="core/template" name="name.button" template="custom/new-button.phtml" /> //unset this block
        </action>
    </reference>
</my_layout_handle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `remove` tag

```
<my_layout_handle>
    <remove name="name.button" />
</my_layout_handle>
```

Or you can simply unset it:

```
<my_layout_handle>
    <reference name="content">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>name.button</name></action>
    </reference>
</my_layout_handle>
```

Comment: I dont want to delete my block, here im in local.xml

Comment: @Prince you said you wanted to remove the block in your question

Comment: Yes of course, but i want to keep my block in local .xml then add tag to not read this block instead of putting comments, for once if ever one day I will need I reactivate it i have just to delete this tag.

Comment: @Prince see my updated answer to unset it

Comment: What do you think about this:
 `<my_layout_handle>` 
`<reference name="content"> `
    `<action method="unsetChild">`
        `<name>name.button</name>`
`<block type="core/template" name="name.button" template="custom/new-button.phtml" />`
    `</action>` 
`</reference>` 
`</my_layout_handle>`